# Error when reading excel (xls) files into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read several excel files using pd.read_excel. However, there is error:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 114-115: unexpected end of data`.

So I tried to add `encoding = "latin1"` and here is the error: `TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'`.

When I saved xls as csv using Excel and then read csv with `encoding="latin1"` it works. However, I want to read xls directly without converting to csv. Is it possible to fix this issue? Thank you.

Edited: the importing works if using xlsx rather than xls.

Comment: Your file might have a different encoding than what you assume. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63478895/6018688 and https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [changed](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html) in pandas 1.1.0. Encoding is no longer a parameter for `read_excel()`.

> read_excel() no longer takes **kwds arguments. This means that passing
> in the keyword argument chunksize now raises a TypeError (previously
> raised a NotImplementedError), while passing in the keyword argument
> encoding now raises a TypeError (GH34464)

You could try the following:

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path, encoding_override='latin1')
df = pd.read_excel(wb)
```

Comment: thank you but there is still error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 114-115: unexpected end of data`

Comment: I was trying this but found out that xlrd is only for .xls files

I have language accents in my excel, when reading from csv I can pass encoding='utf-8'. Why would Pandas remove this ability from reading excel files?

Comment: Ability to read only .xls files is for security purposes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65266497/8217112

Comment: I just downgraded : pip install pandas==1.0.3